# Scanner object will not use filename. Constructor File(file) is undefined

Tags: java

I am using a Scanner to read through lines of a text file given by the user. There is a method to get the file name from the user. I am trying to use the filename in a different method and I get a "`Constructor File(file)` is undefined" error. I tried to simplify the code as much as possible to avoid making the post to long.

```
static File f = getUserFile();
    
    public static File getUserFile() {
        //some code
        return userFile;
    }

    public static void readFile() {
        Scanner userFile = new Scanner(new File(f));
        //loop through text
    }
```

The error occurs on the line where I initialize the Scanner.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `new File(f)` should be just `f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the error message:

> Constructor File(file) is undefined

This has nothing to do with the `Scanner`, it just looks like that because it's on the same line. If you separate the lines like below, the error may be clearer to you:

```java
public static void readFile() {
    File file = new File(f);
    Scanner userFile = new Scanner(file);
    //loop through text
}
```

Now the error will be on the `File file = ...` line.

The problem here is that `f` is already a `File`, and you try to construct a new `File` object passing a `File`. But `File` does not define such a constructor, hence the error. It does define a [constructor that takes a File and a String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,java.lang.String)), but that is not what you used, and not what you probably want --- here the `File` is the parent directory, and the `String` is the actual file name.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and the detailed answer, this helped not only to fix the issue but to clarify why I was having the issues.

Comment: @Rabbit71012 You're welcome, no need to say "thanks". In fact, this may be seen as chatty and get deleted. Stackoverflow's way of saying thanks is upvoting (the upwards pointing triangle) or accepting answers (the checkmark).